# Creating Multiple Candlestick charts from a csv file

Tags: python, excel, csv, candlestick-chart, excel-charts

I am trying to create multiple candlestick charts for given date ranges which I have a list of in Excel. I have OHLC daily price data and need to use this data to create roughly 1100 charts.

I would like these charts to be in a printable format after they have been created.

Also, I would like horizontal lines on each chart, as specified prices.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. "I want this thing, somebody make it for me" is not an appropriate question for this forum.

Comment: Are you looking for python packages to read .csv and .xls? Are you looking to write to Excel?

Comment: We also need to know how is the data stored in the Excel. Separate sheets? Columns? or Aggregated, to make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you check out [pypi](https://pypi.org/) for the python package index. Some useful packages you should look into are [Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/), [MatPlotLib](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/), and [xlrd](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/). If you have a specific question about code that you're working on, please come back and ask.